Django Paginating and order_by at the same time
class QueryLists(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by=4
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset=super().get_queryset()
        queryset=queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        search_filter=self.request.GET.get("search-area")
        if search_filter:
            queryset=queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_filter)
        order_filter=self.request.GET.get("order-by")
        if order_filter:
            queryset=queryset.order_by(order_filter)
        return queryset
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_copy=self.request.GET.copy()
        if 'page' in get_copy:
            print("hello")
            get_copy.pop('page')
        context['get_copy']=urlencode(get_copy)
        return context

I write this code and the url doesn't pop the page when I go to other page for second or third time like this /?page=1&page=2 I want the page appears only once. How can I solve this?

return context["get_copy"]?

Well it will not rewrite the page. Exactly how are you using the get_copy in the template?

I write return context but I have the same problem

but you still don't show how you create a link (with a different ?page=... I presume)?

Previous

The problem is not the copy, you simply still work with the old QueryDict object, so:
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&amp;{{ get_copy }}">Previous</a>
The view should of course use the full context, so:
class QueryLists(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        search_filter = self.request.GET.get('search-area')
        if search_filter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_filter)
        order_filter = self.request.GET.get('order-by')
        if order_filter:
            queryset = queryset.order_by(order_filter)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_copy = self.request.GET.copy()
        get_copy.pop('page', None)
        context['get_copy'] = get_copy.urlencode()
        return context


Note: Please don't allow to order on an arbitrary field, this makes it possible for people to obtain sensitive data, for example when ordering by author__secret, and thus can help exposing data you want to hide.

